# How does Cloudfront/SQS/Lambda handle returning requests back to users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-sqs

Let's say a user needs some information from a database. When the user clicks a button, a request is routed through cloudfront to lambda at edge, which puts the request on an SQS queue. The SQS sends a batch of requests over to a lambda function. For each request, the lambda pulls relevant information from a dynamodb instance and returns it back to the client.

Is this flow possible? What's missing to me here is how the request is actually routed back to the client session. I've worked with API-Gateways where requests are sent to methods. I assume API-Gateway handles the routing here, but it isn't clear to me what exactly is happening when a request goes through cloudfront.

If the flow I first shared doesn't make sense, how would you set up a flow to handle 10,000 or 20,000 of these requests a minute? It seems having lambda handle requests in batches is the only possible way to do this with serverless, individual lambda instances just screw you on the start up/spin down times and costs

Comment: You'd typically implement this with API Gateway and Lambda or Fargate, not CloudFront and Lambda@Edge, I think. But if you genuinely need to support 20k requests per minute (333TPS) then you'd probably consider something running 24x7 e.g. ECS or EC2.

Comment: Got it, yeah so this is a situation where you might consider an actual server?

Could 20k requests not be handled by lambda? If you batched those requests through SQS each lambda could handle, what, 10 or 15? Do batch queries and you don't get hit on latency too hard

Comment: Yes, Lambda can handle 20k requests/minute but you'd want to compare the costs to 24x7 compute. On the SQS front, maybe I mis-read - do you have a typical web client UI that sends an HTTP request then waits for a response? If you don't, then yes it might be sensible to send requests to an SQS and then have them processed (asynchronously) in batches.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I needed clarification there. The web client does wait on a response, but not directly from the lambda. When the request is sent  to cloudfront it gets stored in a database, and (hypothetically) would be routed to this SQS/Lambda stack. So the lambda would just need to update the database